# Can I carry one year medicine of Hypertension while travelling from India to Canada?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, canada, health

I will be travelling from India to Canada for long term assignment. I am on Hypertension Medication([Metpure-XL-25](https://www.lybrate.com/medicine/metpure-xl-25mg-tablet) a pill per day). So can I carry the Medicine for a year with a Doctor's Prescription? Is it allowed?

If yes, then should it be put in Carry-On or Check-In baggage?

Thanks,
Sumukh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to me from reading the [Health Canada guidance](https://www.canada.ca/en/health-canada/services/drugs-health-products/compliance-enforcement/importation-exportation/guidance-document-import-requirements-health-products-under-food-drugs-act-regulations-0084.html#a4) that you can only ever bring a 90-day supply across the border.

You may also have a further 90 day of supplies sent to you from India, as long as it is made clear on the packaging that this medication is for you:

> When a prescription drug is mailed to a Visitor, the drug should be accompanied by some form of documentation indicating that the drug is destined to a Visitor and/or the Visitor should be prepared to provide documentation/written evidence (stamped passport, student/work visa, letter from an employer/university etc) that they are a Visitor to Canada when requested.

The best would be to find a doctor when you arrive into Canada who can prescribe your medication - should be easy enough if it's just tablets for hypertension, not anything there is likely to be restrictions on.

Comment: What does exactly mean "Single Course of treatment" needs to be confirmed as mentioned in "Health Canada guidance" in your answer. What I read is this: "Visitors to Canada may bring into Canada, on their person a single course of treatment or a 90-day supply based on the directions for use, whichever is less, of a prescription drug. "

Comment: @Sam: as it says "whichever is less", a year's supply wouldn't be allowed even if it did class as a single course (which seems unlikely to me, but Canada might have a specialised definition of the term)

Comment: "A course" in medicine refers to a single treatment which lasts over a defined time period as opposed to something ongoing, e.g. a single course of antibiotics would often be less than 90 days and defined as such in the prescription.  I doubt it's a specialised definition, they're just stopping people from taking in any more medication than they personally require.

Comment: It seems to be a beta-blocker so it, or a near equivalent, is likely to be (a) readily available, (b) on doctor's prescription, only in most countries.

Comment: Not answered: you should always carry medications in your carry-on. Never check it. If your bag is lost or the pills are stolen by a baggage inspector (probably not an issue with BP meds), you could find yourself without it for a while.